# Cannot resolve method 'checkuserValidate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String getting error on this while doing login and signup using shared prefences

Tags: android

```
private void checkLogin() {
        String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        boolean isSuccess = mManager.checkuserValidate("username", "password");


        if (isSuccess) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            String message = getString(R.string.login_error_message);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my code i am getting this error while compiling the app
'Cannot resolve method 'checkuserValidate(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Comment: Please provide more code

Comment: Blind guess: `checkuserValidate` should be `checkUserValidate`?